# Reversing the elements of a double linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, reverse

This is my approach-Keep a pointer at the start of the list and a pointer at the end of the list.Advance the head pointer forward and the tail pointer backward until they point the same.
Interchange the values before forwarding.The function throws a segmentation fault when it is called.Why is it so? 
This is my structure for the nodes of the list

```
struct dll
{
 int number;
 struct dll *next;
 struct dll *prev;
};
```

This is my function for reversing the list and the main

```
    int count=0;
void reverse(struct dll **root)
{
 int temp;
 struct dll *tail=NULL;
 struct dll *temproot=NULL;
 temproot =(*root);
 for(;(temproot)->next !=NULL;(temproot)=(temproot)->next); //traversing to the end
 tail= temproot;
 while(((*root)->next != tail->prev) || ((*root)->next != tail))//one for even no. of nodes and one for odd no.of nodes
 {
  temp=(*root)->number; //swapping the numbers
  (*root)->number=tail->number;
  tail->number=temp;
  (*root)=(*root)->next;
  tail=tail->prev;
 } //even after they are same, values need to be changed one last time
   temp=(*root)->number;
  (*root)->number=tail->number;
  tail->number=temp;
  (*root)=(*root)->next;
  tail=tail->prev;
}
void insert(struct dll **root,int num)
{
 struct dll *temp;
 if(count==0)
 {
  if((*root)==NULL)  
  {
  (*root)=(struct dll *)malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
  (*root)->next=NULL;
  (*root)->prev=NULL;
  (*root)->number=num;
  count++;
  printf("\n%d",count);
  }
 }
 else if((*root)->next==NULL) 
  {
  temp=(struct dll *)malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
  temp->next=NULL;
  temp->prev=(*root);
  temp->number=num;
  (*root)->next=temp;
  count++;
  printf("\n%d",count);
  }
 else
 {
  insert(&(*root)->next,num);
 }

}
main()
{
 struct dll *head=NULL;
 int i,n,num;
 while(1)
 {
  printf("Enter 1 for insert, 3 for reverse, 0 for exit\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  switch(n)
  {
   case 1:printf("Enter number\n");
      scanf("%d",&num);
      insert(&head,num);
      break;
   case 3:reverse(&head);break;
   case 0:exit(0);
   default:printf("Enter correct value\n");
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: What line is the segfault on?

Comment: I am a beginner, how do u check what line the segfault is on?

Comment: The best way is to run it in a debugger. I suppose if you don't want to learn how to use a debugger right now you could even just put a `printf` after every line and see which is the last printed.

Comment: You need to give a small complete reproducer. So someone could compile and run without any modification. The problem may not be there in the above code but somewhere else.

Comment: I ran it in a debugger.it says segmentation fault  in the while statement

Comment: I've given a possible answer to your segfault problem separately, but there's another thing to point out. Changing `*root` in the `reverse` function is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. The way this is written, that actually changes the value of the `head` pointer that you're keeping in `main()`. After the `reverse` function finishes, `head` will actually be pointing at the last element in the list.  I think that what you want to do is assign `temproot = *root` at the beginning of your loop, and iterate through the list with `temproot` instead.

Answer (score 0):

By reversing the order of the list, do you mean swapping next and prev pointer for all item ? This piece of unchecked code might do the trick :

```
void reverse(struct dll **root)
{
  struct dll *buff=NULL;
  struct dll *start=*root;

  unsigned char stop=0;
  while(stop==0){
   if(*root==NULL){
    stop=1;
    break;
   }
   buff=(*root)->prev;
   (*root)->prev=(*root)->next;
   (*root)->next=buff;

   *root=(*root)->prev;//the next to treat is the previous one now
   if(*root==start){
    //this test handle the case of "looping" double linked list
    stop=1;
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

This code assumes that *root is the start of the list at start. At the end, *root is still the start of the list.

Bye,

Francis

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although, this is a better logic,I'm using a different one as explained in the question.In my logic,the links for the lists will be the same and root will be the same.It just swaps the numbers,just like for an array

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, *root will _not_ be the same after your program has run.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where this code is hitting a segmentation fault. But if your debugger is saying that it's raising a fault on the line where the `while` statement is written:

```
 while(((*root)->next != tail->prev) || ((*root)->next != tail))//one for even no. of nodes and one for odd no.of nodes
```

then it's almost certain that either `root`, `*root` or `tail` is NULL or is an uninitialized pointer at this point.

One possibility: if you call this function with a linked list that contains exactly one element, then `tail` and `*root` will point to the same element at the beginning of this loop. The way this condition is written, the program will think it needs to continue reversing elements and will continue moving `tail` backward and `*root` forward. Since the program never checks to see if `*root == NULL` or `tail == NULL`, eventually it will walk right off the end of the list and try to dereference a NULL pointer, which will cause a segmentation fault.

It's a very good idea to check that a pointer is NULL, between moving the pointer and dereferencing it. It's also often helpful to think through what happens if you call a function with a list of 0 elements, with a list of 1 element, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I must really really insist that you use a sentry node
for your linked list, it simplifies the code **a lot**.

Once you have converted to using a sentry node, the creation of `reverse`
becomes fairly trivial:

```
struct dll* prev = sentry;

struct dll* curr = sentry->next;
if(curr==sentry) return; // empty list dont need reversing

struct dll* next = curr->next;
if(next==sentry) return; // list size 1 is already its reverse

while( curr != sentry )
{
    // reverse links
    prev->prev = curr;
    curr->next = prev;
    // move to next
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
    next = next->next;
}

// close loop (first item is the one we found last)
sentry->next = prev;
prev->prev = sentry;
```

If you need an example of how a sentry node works, you can look [here](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Answer (score 0):

I write this function that reversing Double Linked List with recursion approach.

```
void Node::Swap(){
 if(m_pNext != NULL){
   m_pNext->Swap();
   m_pNext->m_pNext = this;
 }
}

void List::Reverse(){
  if(m_pHead!=NULL){
    m_pHead->Swap();
    m_pHead->SetNext(NULL);
  }
  Node* pTemp=m_pHead;
  m_pHead = m_pTail;
  m_pTail = pTemp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

struct node{

```
         int data;


         struct node *prev;


         struct node *next;


       };
```

typedef struct node *list;      //just using typedef to shorten things up

list temp=NULL,head=NULL,last=NULL,r=NULL,p=NULL;

/*Create function is used here so last and head now point to last and first node respectively*/

**My function for reversing (Perhaps the shortest)=>**

{

last=head;

r=head;

while(r!=NULL)

{

```
  temp=r->next;


  r->next=r->prev;


  r->prev=temp;  //swapping next and previous using temp


  r=r->prev; //since now values swapped so reverse traversing
```

}

p=last;

while(p->prev!=NULL)

{

```
  p=p->prev;
```

}

head=p;

}